# Outlook email forwarding not working

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, web, forwarding

Exactly as reported [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlookcom-forwarding-setting-disappears/4fd5966b-696c-4344-9c56-bce846e919ad), which is locked and  cannot be replied. Hence asking it here instead.

> Outlook.com forwarding setting disappears.  I re-establish forwarding setting, it keeps disappearing.  Forwarding setting won't stay in place.

> Here's what happens:
>
> - I check the box "Enable forwarding"
> - I enter the other email address I want email to forward to.
> - I check the box "Keep a copy"
>
> But there is no "Save" button, so cannot complete the forward-email process.

As per the article [here](https://www.lifewire.com/forward-outlook-mail-1170648)

[image]

The "Save" is at the URH corner, instead of what the support staff said *"Once it is zoomed out the save button should be located on the bottom part of the page"*

However, this is what I'm getting,

[image]

IE, the save button is not there at all, and related or not, the established forwarding setting keeps disappearing. Forwarding setting won't stay in place.

**UPDATE:** this is not an Office 365 nor a corporate account, just a normal outlook account, and there is no "Save" button no matter how I zoom --

[image]

The UI is obviously different than Christy's screenshot (and I'm using chrome).

Also as per [here](https://www.lifewire.com/forward-outlook-mail-1170648), there is an "Option 2", which is to "Select Settings > View all > Mail > Rules. Add a new rule".

However, after doing that, the forwarded email never arrived, despite my several attempts. When I check, I found that the forward-email rule kept being disabled, despite me kept enabling it. I.E., just like what reported before, *"it keeps disappearing.  Forwarding setting won't stay in place."*

Anyone knows how to get Outlook.com email forwarding work please?

PS. I knew that this legitimate question will be downvoted, or closed. And I knew that my this line will be deleted. Let's just see...

[image]

Comment: are you on a corporate M365 subscription? many orgs won't let you just forward/redirect mail to another mailbox. if that is the case you will have to talk to the M365 admins.

Comment: Questions about Outlook.com belong on Web Applications Stack Exchange not Super User. You can complain about downvotes all you want, but those complaints, have no business being in your question. They belong in a Meta Super User ask for our opinion to improve the quality of your question. Like for instance, remove the meta commentary from your question, complaining about downvotes that didn’t exist or removing unnecessary text that wasn’t removed is a new one for me. You can remove the meta commentary yourself or don’t entirely up to you.

Comment: OWA with regards to Office 365 received significant upgrades and UI changes since that article was written, it’s not applicable, and essentially was written before those significant changes were introduced

Comment: By default, in Microsoft 365, External forwarding is disabled because Microsoft feels this is a security risk. This is what hackers do after your password is compromised, and often the user does not immediately know this is the case. I'm fairly sure that for the same reason, Microsoft does not allow external forwarding on outlook.com

Comment: Outlook web app saves as you proceed for many settings now. There is no save button because it saved when you clicked to change a setting.

Comment: The problem is that everything else can be saved except this email forwarding @music2myear, are you able to do email forwarding on outlook.com using a standalone account?

Comment: Being able to do forwarding is separate from having a Save button in the UI. I was addressing the topic of the save button.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your split-hairs argument has little contribution to address the problem of _the established forwarding setting keeps disappearing. Forwarding setting won't stay in place_

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same exact problem with my account. I solved this downloading the **Outlook app for desktop**, log-in it and set the forward from there. **Don't try to do it from your browser**. Let me know if it worked for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That -1 was not me, but I know the desktop app would work and the question is on its web app.

Comment: Why -1? I tried to give a solution to everyone has the same problem. This community… 

Comment: Yeah, exactly, this ..., I got -1 even for asking the obvious question. It's always like that, when you ask something that big MS cannot handle. Your confirmation of the problem is a GREAT sin, since everybody has been denying it, if you look at all the comments. It seems as if they are thinking that killing the messengers will make the elephant in the room disappear. Edit, I'll make a copy of my comment, as I'm afraid it'll be deleted by someone with so much power that doesn't even need to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I can enable forwarding successfully. As shown in the below image, when you enter the email address and the **Save** option appears in the lower left corner.

[image]

After clicking **Save**, the **Save** option disappears. I found that only the input field email address is changed, the **Save** option will appear.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, your account is Office 365 or corporate account?

Comment: It's just an Outlook.com account.

Comment: Interesting, because as per music2myear's comment left under OP, the Save option should not even be there. Maybe you have your account for many years, and the UI is different between the accounts of different ages, which I found true for my gmail accounts. If you apply for a new normal Outlook.com account today, you'll find the behavior exactly as what I described.

Comment: What about changing to another browser?

Comment: Well, if even chrome is not supported, I doubt that anything else would work, but anyway, what browser are you using? IE, what browser I should be changing to?

Comment: It's just to confirm if the issue is related to your current browser. You can also test Chrome on other computers. And I'm using Edge.

Comment: I thought you use Edge. You might know that Edge use the same engine as Chrome. What you proposed (change browser or computer) might work, but most probably won't work, whereas my proposal, applying for a new normal Outlook.com account, will surely confirm the situation in your own eye, and you can verify yourself that changing browser or computer won't work.

Comment: As you mentioned, i have created a new Outlook.com account and find the same result as yours: the Save option disappeared. I'm afraid that you could post your case in dedicated forum for Outlook.com(https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/outlk_com?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=true&page=1) for more professional advice.

Comment: On the other hand, i also tried to create a rule for the new Outlook.com account, it works. The rule is as following: Condition: Apply to all messages; Action: Forward to: xxxx.xxxx.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue yesterday, no amount of turning on and off the auto forwarding made any difference and the rule i set up to do it was also getting turned off automatically.

So what i ended up doing was to sign into Power Automate and create a simple flow which is doing the forwarding for me.

[image: Power Automate Flow]

Fill out your To: field where you want the emails to go and a comment if you need one. See the enclosed picture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do you sign into Power Automate and how to connect it to Outlook please? Moreover, if it is not a free service, please disclose that in your answer. thx.